# GDB script to count the number of nodes in a brinary tree

Tags: c, gdb, binary-search-tree

I have a core dump and in that I have root pointer of a tree for which I want to count the numbers of nodes that tree has currently.

The below C code returns the numbers of nodes, what will be the equivalent GDB script for the same? Can anybody help me with the GDB script?

```
int count(struct node *root){
    if(root == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 1 + count(root->left) + count(root->right);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but you should be able to quite literally translate your code into a GDB script:

```
(gdb) define lcount
if $arg0 == 0
 return 0
end
return 1 + lcount($arg0->left) + lcount($arg0->right)
end

(gdb) lcount(root)
```

Documentation [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html).

Comment: This doesn't work in the GDB script, I tried, "return" keyword is just another word to it.